# How do I install Ubuntu from my flash drive?

Tags: flash

I got a copy of Ubuntu on my flash drive, but how do I install it on my laptop? It's a Dell Latitude D420. It has an Intel core duo. I took it to have some repairs made and the technician installed Windows 7 on it, only he didn't put in the key so Microsoft wants me to purchase Windows 7. I can't seem to reinstall the Windows XP that came on the machine. I'm stuck. Thanks.

Comment: Naah, I don't think that's a duplicate.  He's booting from a USB stick and wants to create a bootable version of Ubuntu on another USB stick or he'll be totally stuck!

Answer (score 0):

to install ubuntu from a pen drive you need to make it bootable:

from windows use rufus

from linux [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net)
(these are specific softwares made for this reason);

then starting up your pc you should enter the BOOT MENU (usually you should press either F10 or canc button while booting),

choose **try ubuntu**  and you're done_

Answer (score 0):

I suppose someone gave you a fully bootable working version of Ubuntu without installer on a pen drive and you used that to actually ask this question, right?  ;-)

Well, just download the latest and greatest LTS (Long Time Support) version of Ubuntu which you can find here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

And then go to the dash (the left-most upper icon if using vanilla Ubuntu) and click on "Startup Disk Creator", point the "Source disk image" to the ISO file you just downloaded, point the "Disk to use" to **another pen drive then the one you used to boot Ubuntu**. (*you don't want to erase your last lifeline to Ask Ubuntu!!!*)
Click "Make Startup disk" and then shut down Ubuntu, remove your original working bootable pen drive and put it in your pocket (again: no accidental erase!!!) en then boot from the new pen drive and start installing Ubuntu!